# Wrong texture is used when running this in Windows (7 & 10 tested) without graphics drivers installed/in safe mode (OpenGL 1.1 used) is it a bug?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, textures, driver

I'm writing something that I'm wanting to work on as much hardware as possible, but have found an issue where I don't believe that the fault is with my code. can anyone confirm?

**UPDATE - also happens on windows 7, and when booting in safe mode to force no drivers, both are:
OpenGL Version: - 1.1.0,
Vendor: - Microsoft Corporation,
Renderer: - GDI Generic**

when running on windows 10 with an older graphics card, microsoft opengl 1.1 driver is used. yeah, i know that shaders are the way to go, and that older cards aren't actually supported on windows 10, but since when did that stop anyone... etc. but like i said, I'm wanting maximum compatibility. Code that demonstrates the issue is included:-

```
//link library
//opengl32

//linker options
//-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

//include SDL2 dirs-
//compiler-
//SDL2-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2
//linker-
//SDL2-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib


#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>


void draw();

bool fix = false;
bool wire = false;

GLuint tex1 = 0;
GLuint tex2 = 0;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_TIMER);

    SDL_Window* mywindow = SDL_CreateWindow("press q or w to toggle fixes...",100,100,640,480,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL|SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_GL_CreateContext(mywindow);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);



    bool loop = true;
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    while (loop)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                loop = false;

            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    loop = false;
                    break;
                case SDLK_q:
                    fix = !fix;
                break;

                case SDLK_w:
                    if(wire)
                    {
                        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
                    }
                    wire = !wire;
                break;




                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        draw();
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mywindow);
    }
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDeleteTextures(1, &tex1);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &tex2);


    return 0;
}




void texturator(GLuint* tex, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
{
    if(!(*tex))
    {
        glGenTextures(1, tex) ;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex);

        unsigned char text[4*4*4];//4*w*h
        for(unsigned int x = 0;x<4;x++)
        {
            for(unsigned int y = 0;y<4;y++)
            {
                unsigned char* pix = &(text[((y*4)+x)*4]);
                pix[0] = x*r;
                pix[1] = y*g;
                pix[2] = x*b;
                pix[3] = 255;
            }
        }

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    }
    else
    {
        if(fix)
        {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex);
    }
}





void draw()
{



    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLfloat mat1[] = {1.0, 0, 0, 0,    0, 1.0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 1.0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 1};
    glLoadMatrixf(mat1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLfloat verts[] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,  1.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f,0.0f};
    GLfloat uvs[] = {0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f};

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvs);



    texturator(&tex1,0,60,60);


    GLuint elem[] = {0,1,2, 2,3,0};
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, elem);



    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLfloat mat2[] = {1, 0, 0, 0,    -0, 1, 0, 0,     0, 0, 1, 0,    -1, 0, 0, 1};
    glLoadMatrixf(mat2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();



    texturator(&tex2,60,10,0);



    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvs);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);


}
```

from the second frame on, tex2 will continue to be displayed for both draws, even though gdebugger says that tex1 is bound. binding 0 before the new bind fixes this. switching to wireframe instead of fill mode also, curiously, fixes it, whilst it is still drawn as wireframe. (use q and w keys to toggle these).

can anyone shed any light on this? is it just microsoft's implementation being..............
and is there a better way to include compatibility with older stuff?

cheers!!